# iOS: Creating a method that can be used by different objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, subclass, class-method, objective-c-category

I'm trying to create a method that can be called from any object that has a property `backgroundColor`. Should I subclass `NSObject` and add a class method or is there a different way to do something like this, that doesn't require adding a category for every object.

Something along the lines of:

```
[self.myLabel addAwesomeLayerWithSomeColor:(UIColor *)color];
[self.myView addAwesomeLayerWithSomeColor:(UIColor *)color];
[self.myButton addAwesomeLayerWithSomeColor:(UIColor *)color];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want this method to be usable on views and subclasses of views. The correct thing to do would be to make a category on `UIView`. Then, all of these subclasses and any others will be able to use this method.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm. Appreciate the explanation.

Comment: Categories are awesome. I set them up in UIImage, UIStoryboard, UIColor so I can easily get the elements I need.